# What is the proper way to escape JSON that may contain HTML before rendering it in HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I found many similar questions, but not one that would discuss this scenario.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send(`<html>
<body>
Hello, World!
</body>
<script>
const test = ${JSON.stringify({html: '</script><script>alert(1)</script>'})};
</script>
  
</html>`);
});
```

This will produce HTML as follows:

```html
<html>
<body>
Hello, World!
</body>
<script>
const test = {"html":"</script><script>alert(1)</script>"};
</script>
  
</html>
```

which as you can see, allows injection from JSON.

Here is a quick replit: https://stylishtrustysupercollider.gajus.repl.co/

Assuming that JSON contains arbitrary content that we have no control over, what is the correct way to handle this scenario?

Considering producing base64 encoded string but it feels like an overkill.

Comment: encodeURI or encodeURIComponent

Comment: The entire JSON output?

Comment: There are many [HTML sanitization routines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) out there...

Comment: You missed part of the question – I do not have control over the JSON's content.

Comment: >The entire JSON output? - Normally, yeah. This will stop script injection

Comment: It's because the output isn't JSON? Try `const test = JSON.parse('{"html":"</script><script>alert(1)</script>"}')`

Comment: So then `JSON.stringify` produces non-JSON output? The code is available here to play around https://replit.com/@gajus/StylishTrustySupercollider

Comment: @Gajus the output should be `'{"html":"</script><script>alert(1)</script>"}';` which is a string

Comment: @evolutionxbox — That still puts the sequence `</script>` in the HTML source code, so the HTML parser will terminate the script half way through the string literal and then start a new one completely under the control of the author of the JSON.

Comment: @Quentin it does? https://replit.com/@gajus/StylishTrustySupercollider doesn't seem to show that

Comment: @evolutionxbox — the code in that link is completely different to what you just proposed: `const test = JSON.parse('{"html":"</script><script>alert(1)</script>"}')`

Comment: Sorry, looks like the Replit link is not versioned. I ended up with a solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76621641/368691

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an HTML aware template language (which will take care of any escaping needed to make it safe to insert the string in a "normal" (i.e. not in the middle of a `<script>` element) part of document
2. Store the data in an attribute instead of treating JSON as JS source code (so that HTML escaping is sufficient).

e.g.

*server.js*

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const foo = JSON.stringify({ html: '</script><script>alert(1)</script>' });
    res.render('index', { foo });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
```

*views/index.ejs*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Hello, World!
    </body>
    <script data-foo="<%= foo %>">
        const test = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.dataset.foo);
        console.log(test);
    </script>
</html>
```

You could replace step 1 with your own HTML escaping routines, but I generally prefer something tried and tested.

Comment: I appreciate this as a suggestion, but "use a library" is not an answer to my question. I seeking to understand the underlying proper handling of the data.

Comment: @Gajus — I refer you to the last paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am surprised this is necessary, but it appears that the answer is a variation of:

```
// arbitrary JSON document
const json = {
  html: '</script><script>alert(1)</script>'
};

const html = `
<script>
const test = JSON.parse(
  decodeURI(
    "${encodeURI(
      JSON.stringify(json)
    )}"
  )
);
</script>
`;
```

or to break it down...

1. we are creating a JSON string with `JSON.stringify`
2. we are encoding characters such as `<` and `>` using `encodeURI`
3. we render the encoded string
4. we decode the string with `decodeURI`
5. we parse JSON

`encodeURI` / `decodeURI` could also be replaced with alternative encoding mechanisms.

As pointed out by Quentin, this is not safe unless you explicitly wrap the output with `"` rather than `'`. This seems like an easy mistake to make and not worth the risk.

I took a quick glance at existing libraries for escaping/unescaping HTML and identified that it basically falls down to escaping `&`, `<`, `>`, `'` and `"` characters.

The following code is taken from [`html-escaper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-escaper):

```
/**
 * Copyright (C) 2017-present by Andrea Giammarchi - @WebReflection
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */

const {replace} = '';

// escape
const es = /&(?:amp|#38|lt|#60|gt|#62|apos|#39|quot|#34);/g;
const ca = /[&<>'"]/g;

const esca = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  '"': '&quot;'
};
const pe = m => esca[m];

/**
 * Safely escape HTML entities such as `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, and `'`.
 * @param {string} es the input to safely escape
 * @returns {string} the escaped input, and it **throws** an error if
 *  the input type is unexpected, except for boolean and numbers,
 *  converted as string.
 */
export const escape = es => replace.call(es, ca, pe);


// unescape
const unes = {
  '&amp;': '&',
  '&#38;': '&',
  '&lt;': '<',
  '&#60;': '<',
  '&gt;': '>',
  '&#62;': '>',
  '&apos;': "'",
  '&#39;': "'",
  '&quot;': '"',
  '&#34;': '"'
};
const cape = m => unes[m];

/**
 * Safely unescape previously escaped entities such as `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`,
 * and `'`.
 * @param {string} un a previously escaped string
 * @returns {string} the unescaped input, and it **throws** an error if
 *  the input type is unexpected, except for boolean and numbers,
 *  converted as string.
 */
export const unescape = un => replace.call(un, es, cape);
```

Using the latter approach/library is preferable over attempting to escape with `encodeURI` or similar approaches.

Comment: "I do find it surprising that these characters are not encoded by default by JSON format." — Why would characters with special meaning in HTML, but no special meaning in JSON, be encoded by default by a JSON encoder?

Comment: **Danger — This is unsafe**: `encodeURI` is designed for encoding URIs not JavaScript string literals. It does not encode `'` characters but your code wraps the output of `encodeURI` with `'` characters to dynamically generate a string literal.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: "I took a quick glance at existing libraries for escaping/unescaping HTML" — … but you're not simply inserting the value into HTML. You're inserting it in JS and then inserting that JS into HTML which adds an extra layer of complexity and risk (hence why I recommended avoiding doing that in my earlier answer).

Comment: Oh, and I don't think the MIT license is compatible with the  CC BY-SA license which makes posting that edit a copyright risk.

Comment: You are just spreading FUD. MIT license _is_ compatible with CC BY-SA if attribution is included, which it is.